# Making a Query with the output from two table with a common key

Tags: mysql, join

I am new to SQL so when I tried to look for an existing answer, I cannot find any due to my lack of vocab in SQL. So if there are already a question about this please link me to it, Thank you very much.

Here is my question
I have two table
[order table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyAhm.png)
and [customer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh8Ue.png)

I found the order dates using the query below

```
select orderDate
from order_
where orderID in(
    select orderID
    from order_item
    where productID in(
        select productID
            from product
            where productName in('Overwatch', 'The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim')));
```

i also found the first and last name of people who make the purchase

```
select firstName, lastName
from customer
where customerID in(
    select customerID
    from order_
    where orderID in(
        select orderID
            from order_item
            where productID in(
                select productID
                    from product
                    where productName in('Overwatch', 'The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim'))))
```

when i have the order date, i want to make a query, to show last name, first name from the customer table correspond to the order date i found
the common key from they two table is the customerID key.

I need the output to be like

firstname, lastname, orderDate

i try all types of join and union, but i might have been doing something wrong.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it is a solution or not,because I didn't even try it. But you should give this a shot.

```
select customer.firstName, customer.lastName, order_.orderDate
from order_, customer
where order.customerID = customer.customerID in(
select customerID
    from order_
    where orderID in(
        select orderID
            from order_item
            where productID in(
                select productID
                    from product
                    where productName in('Overwatch', 'The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim'))))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it didn't work, but it help me think of the answer.
this is the answer i thought of any it works :)
      select firstName, lastName,state, orderDate
      from(
 select customerID, orderDate
        from order_
        where orderID in(
            select orderID
            from order_item
            where productID in(
                    select productID
                    from product
                    where productName in('Overwatch', 'The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim')))) temp
inner join customer
on customer.customerID = temp.customerID;'

Comment: Yes, temporary table make sense. I am glad it helped somehow. May the force be with you. :)